# Do I have to close realm on a per thread-basis, or per usage/class-basis?

Tags: android, realm

If I have a MainActivity like this:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        // Set up database
        RealmConfiguration realmConfiguration = new RealmConfiguration.Builder(this).build();
        Realm.deleteRealm(realmConfiguration); // Clean slate
        Realm.setDefaultConfiguration(realmConfiguration); // Make this Realm the default

        realm = Realm.getDefaultInstance();
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        realm.close();
        super.onDestroy();
    }
}
```

And I use `realm.getDefaultInstance()` in another class (same thread) like this:

```
public class ViewBookActivity extends Activity {
    private Realm realm;

    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_scan_result);

        realm = Realm.getDefaultInstance();
    }
}
```

Should I then call `realm.close()` in `onDestroy()` in `ViewBookActivity`? Or is it sufficient to close it in `MainActivity`?

Realm documentation says:

> Realm instances are reference counted, which means that if you call
>   getInstance() twice in a thread, you will also have to call close()
>   twice as well.

But I'm not sure if this applies to `getDefaultInstance()`.

Also, is it OK to stick to `Realm.getDefaultInstance()`, even in other threads, if I close it when I'm done writing to it? I don't really understand the potential usage of `Realm.getInstance(Context context)`.

Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Best practise is that if you open the Realm in `onCreate` you should close it again in `onDestroy` in all your activities as it means you reference count will reach 0 when all your activities have closed. So in your case: Yes, you should do it in both `MainActivity` and `ViewBookActivity`

With regard to `Realm.getDefaultInstance()`. That is just a shorthand for `Realm.getInstance(myConfig)`, so you have to call `close()` on those as well.

`Realm.getInstance(Context)` is just a shorthand for `Realm.getInstance(new RealmConfiguration.Builder(context).build())` and is intended to make it really easy to get started with Realm in small examples. If you plan to create a larger app you should create your configuration manually. But I agree it can be confusing and we should probably consider removing it all together.

Comment: `if you open the Realm in onCreate you should close it again in onDestroy in all your activities` Especially now that you've fixed the ANRs on opening during write transactions in 0.83.0 :P (nice job by the way, you guys are great)

Comment: Ok. What if I use the Realm DB in a class (same thread) that is not an activity (or fragment or anything like that), like a static controller-class, and I'm not particularly keen on doing `Realm.getDefaultInstance()` and `realm.close()` in each method? Is it OK to create "fake" `onCreate()` and `onDestroy()` methods, and call them in the `onCreate()` and `onDestroy()` methods in the `MainActivity` class? I realize that the database instance will stay open as long as the app is open, but is this a problem?

Comment: Yes, that would be fine as well.